# Find duplicate passwords in Windows domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Does anyone have a recommended procedure or toolset to detect duplicate passwords between user accounts in a Windows Active Directory domain? (DC is Windows Server 2012, FWIW)

I strongly suspect some of our shifts are sharing passwords.  Obviously the reset policy keeps them from making them permanent, but I wouldn't be surprised if they are "synchronizing" between themselves.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how AD stores passwords, but detecting identical passwords is impossible with all decent password hashing schemes. Cracking one password would crack it for all people who share it, which is not very nice and can be mitigated by salting.

Comment: As gronostaj says, salting means that even if two people share the same password, they would be stored differently. This is more of a HR issue than an IT issue. Remind them of your acceptable use policy, and if you see account sharing lock the account and refer them.

Comment: Sounds like you suspect you have personnel sharing accounts.  This is more of an HR issue.  You won't be able to detect duplicate passwords.

Comment: HR won't be involved unless I can prove it's happening.  You can't enforce what you can't measure.  Thanks.